# Google Font Rendering Issues? Roboto

Tags: wordpress, css, fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

Has anyone ran into any rendering issues with Roboto?  I'm having an issues on some mobile devices where the "s" and "t" and rendering together.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to correct the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature). It is a holdover from the days of metal type and is usually used with *tt*, *ff*, *fi*, *fj* and *fl*, *ffi*, and so on. You can see another one in your screen shot with the text "fill-up" on the third line of your first event (look at the *fi*). Using it with *st* is just decoration.

You have some control over this in CSS with [`font-variant-ligatures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures). As of now, [support is pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-variant-ligatures).

Without knowing what "some mobile devices" in your question encompasses, it will be up to you test. Some options:

- [`font-variant-ligatures: none;`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-variant-ligatures) should disable all ligatures (which may or may not be what you want).
- [`font-variant-ligatures: no-discretionary-ligatures;`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-variant-ligatures) will disable ligatures that the designer identified as discretionary, so you will need to either give it a go (and see if the font designer set *st* as discretionary) or look at the font itself to glean that info.
- [`font-feature-settings: none;`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#descdef-font-feature-settings) should disable all ligatures.
- the non-standard [`text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-rendering/) may also do the trick.

Comment: That did it, I had no idea.  Thanks.

Comment: Which CSS ended up working best for you (ideally with the browsers as well)?

Answer (score 0):

just put this on your CSS

```
font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;
```